# Storing and iterating through a collection of objects with unrelated interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have a group of POJOs that are unrelated in their interface (ex. one might store an `int` and a `boolean`, one may store only a `String`, etc.). They are, however, logically part of the same group - they are objects representing different types of updates with different data models depending on the specific type of update. I want to have a collection of these "update" objects and iterate through them, handling each concrete event differently depending on the class.

My thought on how to approach this is to use the visitor pattern, but I wasn't sure if the visitor pattern can/should be used with objects that aren't directly inheriting from the same superclass or implementing a common interface. Is having an interface like below where the only unifying factor is the `accept` method a valid approach, or is there a better-suited design approach for a case like this? I would then presumably have a `Collection<Update>` which I would iterate over.

```
public interface Update {
   public void accept(UpdateVisitor visitor);
}
```

Comment: If you are stil looking for an answer, you have to post two or three of those related classes. From your vague description I doubt that the Visitor is the right solution. It solves a different problem. You are simply asking for polymorphism. When writing serious code you should always depend on interfaces or abstractions. In this context you would have to extract common attributes to an interface and common behavior to an abstract class. Alternatively you must store the items in a collection of type `object` and then cast each item to use it. This is not recommend.

Comment: @BionicCode Maybe a more concrete example that would be similar is like if I want to provide clients a way to access an ordered collection of REST API requests that happened in a specific time period. GET request objects may have different fields than POST request objects. Maybe one client wants to aggregate a list based on a field only in the GET request type and ignore other request types. Maybe another client wants to extract specific POST-request only properties. Seems like a visitor gives this type of flexibility. I can't store them in separate collections since I need to preserve order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visitor does not require a common interface (beyond its own). Its limitation is that it only applies to a small number of types, and those types should be fixed. If you have only a handful of different updates, and you do not expect to add more in the future, then Visitor is a valid solution.

Alternatively, don't attempt to combine all updates into a single collection. Maintain the type information in separate collections and process them in separate handlers. This solution can scale where the Visitor cannot.